# Google Charts Dashboard: How to make it responsive?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm building a Google charts dashboard but I'm having difficulty making it responsive. I've tried using the function added to normal Google charts, as opposed to Dashboards, which works great but it's not having the same impact. Please see my code below. The code I'm trying to use to responsify the dashboard is at the bottom

Thanks
Aaron

```
 google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['controls','linechart']});
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
function initialize() {
  // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHnIbV5ZLjmcFXRfGx8hHVkLoYzYMMJlV3lk4Cr-R7I/edit?usp=sharing');


  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  // Everything is loaded. Assemble your dashboard...
  var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Name',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
  });
  var laptimeChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'LineChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div'
  });

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div')).
    bind(namePicker, laptimeChart).
    draw(data)

}
$(window).resize(function() {
  draw(data);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close, but a couple things...

1. although `bind` returns the `dashboard` (for chaining multiple binds),
   `draw` does not return the `dashboard`, need to call separately to save `dashboard` instance
2. the `'resize'` listener needs to be in the same scope as `dashboard` and
   you must include the reference to `dashboard` when calling `draw`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: initialize,
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
});

function initialize() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHnIbV5ZLjmcFXRfGx8hHVkLoYzYMMJlV3lk4Cr-R7I/edit?usp=sharing');
  query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Name',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    }
  });
  var laptimeChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div'
  });

  // save reference to dashboard
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div')).
    bind(namePicker, laptimeChart);
  dashboard.draw(data);

  // include within drawDashboard
  $(window).resize(function() {
    // reference dashboard instance
    dashboard.draw(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: also recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, vs. `jsapi`