# google chart a.S is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

i have the following directive:

```
angular.module('Division').directive('divisionChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'js/helpers/Division/directives/division-chart/division-chart.html',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var data = {
                "cols": [
                    {"label": "Name", "pattern": "", "type": "string"},
                    {"label": "Manager", "pattern": "", "type": "string"},
                    {"label": "ToolTip", "pattern": "", "type": "string"}
                ],
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "c": [
                            {"v": "1", "f": "Mike O."},
                            {"v": ""},
                            {"v": "The President"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "c": [
                            {"v": "2", "f": "Jim"},
                            {"v": "1"},
                            {"v": "VP"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "c": [
                            {"v": "3", "f": "Alice"},
                            {"v": "1"},
                            {"v": ""}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "c": [
                            {"v": "4", "f": "Bob"},
                            {"v": "2"},
                            {"v": "Bob Sponge"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "c": [
                            {"v": "Carol"},
                            {"v": "4"},
                            {"v": ""}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };


            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(element[0]);
            chart.draw(data);
        }
    }
});
```

That has the following HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

When i attempt to run this i get the following error:

```
TypeError: a.S is not a function
```

I have made sure to include the googlechart in my index:

```
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?ext.js"></script>
<script>google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['orgchart']});</script>
```

So can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, recommend using the current loader for the google charts library...

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

only thing that changes is the `load` statement, which follows...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

note the `callback`, as with the `jsapi` loader, the `load` statement has a `callback`
you shouldn't create from the following namespaces until the callback has fired

`google.charts`
`google.visualization`

Comment: thank you it did. Do you know anything about making it responsive? because im a chart with alot of data and it seems to overflow on my site

Comment: just need to redraw the chart on `window` `'resize'` -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37412664/5090771)